# How to add a background color for div tag in README.md

Tags: github, readme, readme.io

I tried this code but it is not working

```
| <div bgcolor='red'>[<img  src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@3.0.1/icons/github.svg' alt='github' height='20'>](https://github.com/HuKKu-ec)</div> |<div > ABc </div>|
| -------- | ----------- |
```

I am trying to give some white background for my github logo because the logo color is black which is not good looking in github bio in dark.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add this class to your div.

```
<div class="background: white;">
```

Comment: Its not working

Comment: @HukbathEc why not working? can you give link?

Comment: `|<div class="background: blue;"> [<img  src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-icons@3.0.1/icons/github.svg' alt='github' height='20'>](https://github.com/HuKKu-ec)   | <div>  asdsds </div>  |
| ------------- |------------- |`    you may preview this code using any of live preview tools

Answer (score 0):

Put this on the div tag:

```
style="background: white;"
```